# How do I bring the search circle from leaflet.extras::addSearchOSM() to front of leaflet/tmap map?

Tags: r, leaflet, mapping, choropleth, tmap

I am trying to bring the blue search circle from the addSearchOSM() function from leaflet.extras above a choropleth map made by tmap and converted to leaflet. Does anybody know how to bring the blue circle forward so it can be viewed when the polygon layer is selected. A reprex is below. The image linked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSDvy.png) shows the blue circle when the data layer (nz) is not selected, but when it is selected, the blue circle is covered. Thank you in advance for the help.

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(tmap)
library(spData)

#create tmap
nz <- tm_shape(nz) + tm_polygons()

#Create leaflet map from tmap and add search
nz_leaflet <- tmap_leaflet(nz) %>% 
    leaflet.extras::addSearchOSM()
```

Unlike markers, the addSearchOSM() function does not have a zIndex marker, but I looked for it and feel like I need some sort of solution similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML there's a the z-index CSS attribute, essentially controlling layer order. There's something in the tmap leaflet function setting that to 401 and the osm search is set to 400 by default. To bring the base layer (nz) to front, one should use the `zindex` argument of the `tm_polygons()` function. We need this zindex to be lower than 400 such that the circle generated from `addSearchOSM()` is over the map. That could look like:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(tmap)
library(spData)

#create tmap
nz <- tm_shape(nz) + tm_polygons(zindex = 399)

#Create leaflet map from tmap and add search
nz_leaflet <- tmap_leaflet(nz) %>% 
    leaflet.extras::addSearchOSM()
```